# Is it possible to setCookie() in Laravel 5 before returning from the controller method?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I have some sample code within a controller method that looks up a cookie and manipulates the model if it exists, or creates a new model and returns a new cookie if it doesn't.

**Is it possible to add the cookie before I return the view such that the duplicated code can be written only once?**

I'm just looking for efficiency and tidiness.

```
$cat = Cat::find($request->cookie('cat_id'));
if (null !== $cat) {
    if ($cat->name === 'Felix') {
        $cat->age = 10;
    } else {
        $cat->age = 8;
    }

    //duplicated code
    $cat->fur = 'soft';
    $cat->tail = 'wavy';
    $cat->save();

    return redirect('/');

} else {
    $cat = new Cat;
    $cat->name = 'Ralf';
    $cat->age = 12;

    //duplicated code
    $cat->fur = 'soft';
    $cat->tail = 'wavy';
    $cat->save();

    return redirect('/')->withCookie(cookie('cat_id', $cat->id,10000));
}
```

Comment: Use a service provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `redirect()` method returns a `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` when a string is passed to it, which the Laravel routing stack interprets as a direction to send out a particular response header. So instead of returning twice, you can just do this:

```
$cat = Cat::find($request->cookie('cat_id'));
$redirect = redirect('/');

if (null !== $cat) {
    if ($cat->name === 'Felix') {
        $cat->age = 10;
    } else {
        $cat->age = 8;
    }

    //duplicated code
    $cat->fur = 'soft';
    $cat->tail = 'wavy';
    $cat->save();
} else {
    $cat = new Cat;
    $cat->name = 'Ralf';
    $cat->age = 12;

    //duplicated code
    $cat->fur = 'soft';
    $cat->tail = 'wavy';
    $cat->save();

    $redirect->withCookie(cookie('cat_id', $cat->id,10000));
}

return $redirect;
```